# Difference between REST API URLs

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to understand what the difference between the two REST URLs used for fetching aggregation data in the Yodlee API. In particular, when I look at the sample API calls in Test Drive, the base REST URL that is used is:

> https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/

But when I looked in the API Docs (https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php) and in the `Config.js` file of the Node.JS sample application, the base REST URL that is used it:

> https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl

I want to know what the difference between these two URLs are and which one I should really be using for both testing and production. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl` is used for new *Yodlee REST API*, and the `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/`is the old one (*Aggregation REST API*).

Of course, Yodlee through mailing lists encourages developers to use new style api (so that's the one you should be using), but the documentation is less then ideal for it, so prepare for dragons ahead.

It doesn't help either that old api throughout Yodlee web site is sometimes just called "REST API", and sometimes the new one is also just called "REST API" without anyway to quickly distinguish for which one is the documentation.

For me the easiest way to distinguish new api from old one is the way version is declared in example urls:

- **new** (Yodlee) api: `/v1/`
- **old** (REST) api: `/v1.0/`